# How to solve problem with PATH_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED in moveit?

Tags: gazebo, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am facing with problem when I want to execute my trajectory in moveit and see it in Gazebo because of error which says:

```
Controller failed with error PATH_TOLERANCE_VIOLATED
```

what should I do to solve this error and how to do it? Should I somehow decrease path tolerance maybe?
if any other information needs to be provided I will be glade to provide it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325103/how-to-solve-problem-with-path_tolerance_violated-in-moveit?/) by [lbajlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42054/lbajlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error is triggered when your (real or simulated) robot is unable to follow the planned trajectory precisely enough. There could be several different root causes of this.

A. The controllers on your robot may not be well tuned, so that the error between their set point and actual position becomes too great. If you've built your own robot in Gazebo this may be likely.

B. The path planner has produced a trajectory which the robot is physically incapable of following. If the speed or acceleration limits of the joints are set unrealistically high then the trajectory will be impossible for the robot to follow.

C. The path tolerance may be set unrealistically fine.

Things to try:

- Lower the speed and acceleration multipliers in the Moveit GUI (or API if you're using that)
- Try improving the tuning of your PID controllers if you made the robot yourself.
- Increase the path tolerance, but make sure your robot is still accurate enough to achieve its task and safely avoid collisions.

Also can describe your robot model in Gazebo, is it a ready made one or have you make it yourself?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lbajlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42054/lbajlo/) on 2020-01-09**:
Hi Peter,thanks for answer. This part with increasing tolerance was helpful. Sorry for accepting answer so late but I didn't notice that you answered on my question here.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2020-01-09**:
No problem, glad it helped.

**Comment by [ryanc](https://answers.ros.org/users/51159/ryanc/) on 2020-11-23**:
Hi @PeteBlackerThe3rd and @lbajlo, how can I decrease the tolerance?

Edit: to change the path tolerance, open the controller and next to the joint you'll see {trajectory: __, goal: ___}  to change the path tolerance change the trajectory value and goal tolerance with the goal value